# Validation textbox in binding with datagrid

Tags: vb.net, validation, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I have this Grid with **"SelectedItem binding with SelectRowGrid"**

```
     <DataGrid 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Dati_Cliente, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectRowGrid, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
            Style="{DynamicResource ST_DataGrid}" 
            CellStyle="{DynamicResource St_DataGridCellStyle}" SelectionMode="Single"  Name="Dg_Dati">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Id_Cli}" Header="Id Cliente"  Width="Auto" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Desc}" Header="Descrizione" Width="Auto" />
```

etc....

The columns **Id_Cli** and **Desc** are in *Binding with 2 textboxs*.

```
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding SelectRowGrid.Id_Cli, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, 
                ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Margin="4,4,4,4"  MaxLength="11"/>

            <TextBox Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectRowGrid.Desc, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, 
                ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Margin="4,4,4,4"   MaxLength="100"/>
```

Every time that I click on a single row, the textboxs are populated without problems, and if I change a text value, this new value is update on  row grid.

**But this is my issue**. Why, if the thextbox is empty, I don't see the red border around the textbox ?

Why this code doesn't work.

```
        Public ReadOnly Property [Error]() As String Implements System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo.Error
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
    End Property
    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal Name As String) As String Implements System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo.Item
        Get
            Dim result As String = Nothing
            If Name = "SelectRowGrid" Then

                If SelectRowGrid IsNot Nothing Then
                    If IsNothing(SelectRowGrid.Id_Cli) Then
                        result = "Item number cannot be blank!"
                    End If
                    If IsNothing(SelectRowGrid.Desc) Then
                        result = "Item number cannot be blank!"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            Return result
        End Get
    End Property
```

p.s. in my code I implemented IDataErrorInfo and  INotifyPropertyChanged,

**Fixed.
I changed and moved this code in the class MyClass**

New Code:

```
        Public ReadOnly Property [Error]() As String Implements System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo.Error
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
    End Property
    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal Name As String) As String Implements System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo.Item
        Get
            Dim result As String = Nothing
            If Name.Equals("Id_Cli") Then
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Id_Cli) Then
                    Return "Error !"
                End If
            End If
            If Name.Equals("Desc") Then
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Desc) Then
                    Return "Error !"
                End If
            End If

            Return result
        End Get
    End Property
```